# trigger javascript event handler already registered on a plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

*Sorry for the title gore, will edit as appropriate..*

I am using the [Twitter Bootstrap Wizard](http://vadimg.com/twitter-bootstrap-wizard-example/) for handling database manipulation. I would really like to be able to trigger the `onTabShow()` function at the press of a button. `onTabShow()` loads the data and generates an updated form, so this ability to register some kind of event would be of great help. The function is defined as below:

```
$('#location_wizard').bootstrapWizard({
        ...
        onTabClick: function (tab, navigation, index, clickedIndex) {
            ...
        },
        onNext: function (tab, navigation, index) {
            ...
        },
        onPrevious: function (tab, navigation, index) {
            ...
        },
        onTabShow: function (tab, navigation, index) {
            TRIGGER THIS FUNCTION WITHOUT SWITCHING PAGES!
        }
});
```

How might I write something like

```
('#add-new').on('click', function() {
    ... AJAX some stuff ...
    ... trigger "onTabShow()" without switching tabs in the wizard ...
})
```

Comment: can´t you just use a function inside onTabShow and call that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract your "on tab show" handler from the plugin, so you can call the function from different parts of your code.

```
$('#location_wizard').bootstrapWizard({
    //...
    onTabShow: onTabShowHandler
    //...
});

$('#add-new').on('click', function(){
    //... ajax ...
    onTabShowHandler(x, y, z);
});

function onTabShowHandler(tab, navigation, index){
    // do tab show stuff
}
```

**EDIT: additional details**

> since x, y, z are provided within bootstrapWizard, how might I access
>   those when triggering onTabShowHandler from the click event?

You will have to pass those arguments to the function yourself. If you inspect each of those arguments when `onTabShowHandler` is triggered by the `bootstrapWizard` plugin, you'll see their values and be able to mock something similar.

```
function onTabShowHandler(tab, navigation, index){
    console.log(tab);        // element/jQuery object
    console.log(navigation); // element/jQuery object
    console.log(index);      // number
}

// in your click function...
$('#add-new').on('click', function(){
    var x = $('#tab-1');
    var y = $('#nav');
    var z = 0;

    onTabShowHandler(x, y, z); // reacts as though tab 1 was shown
});
```

Comment: since `x, y, z` are provided within `bootstrapWizard`, how might I access those when triggering `onTabShowHandler` from the `click` event?

Comment: added detail to the original answer.